# Why the pages can't get show in my Django CRUD application?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

I try to learn Django CRUD from this tutorial:
https://www.javatpoint.com/django-crud-example
My Django version is 2.1.7 and my IDE is VisualStudio.
When I run the project all the pages have an error. the error cames bellow.

```
 TemplateDoesNotExist at /index
show.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:52322/index
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
show.html
Exception Location: E:\Django_Try\DjangoWebProject5\DjangoWebProject5\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 19
Python Executable:  E:\Django_Try\DjangoWebProject5\DjangoWebProject5\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.6
Python Path:    
['E:\\Django_Try\\DjangoWebProject5\\DjangoWebProject5',
 '',
 'E:\\Django_Try\\DjangoWebProject5\\DjangoWebProject5',
 'E:\\Django_Try\\DjangoWebProject5\\DjangoWebProject5\\env\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64',
 'E:\\Django_Try\\DjangoWebProject5\\DjangoWebProject5\\env',
 'E:\\Django_Try\\DjangoWebProject5\\DjangoWebProject5\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 5 Mar 2019 22:43:24 +0000
```

I add my Urls bellow:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin  
from django.urls import path  
from employee import views  

urlpatterns = [  
    path('index', views.show), 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),  
    path('emp', views.emp),  
    path('show',views.show),  
    path('edit/<int:id>', views.edit), 
    path('update/<int:id>', views.update),  
    path('delete/<int:id>', views.destroy),  
]
```

View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect  
from employee.forms import EmployeeForm  
from employee.models import Employee  
# Create your views here.  
def emp(request):  
    if request.method == "POST":  
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            try:  
                form.save()  
                return redirect('/show')  
            except:  
                pass  
    else:  
        form = EmployeeForm()  
    return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form})  
def show(request):  
    employees = Employee.objects.all()  
    return render(request,"show.html",{'employees':employees})  
def edit(request, id):  
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  
    return render(request,'edit.html', {'employee':employee})  
def update(request, id):  
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST, instance = employee)  
    if form.is_valid():  
        form.save()  
        return redirect("/show")  
    return render(request, 'edit.html', {'employee': employee})  
def destroy(request, id):  
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  
    employee.delete()  
    return redirect("/show")
```

setting:

```
"""
Django settings for DjangoWebProject5 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import posixpath

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '65ccf984-10e5-4c13-ab4d-9c0cf30e8b04'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Add your apps here to enable them
    'employee',  
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'DjangoWebProject5.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DjangoWebProject5.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = posixpath.join(*(BASE_DIR.split(os.path.sep) + ['static']))
```

the project structure is completely like the tutorial an image cames bellow:

https://www.javatpoint.com/django/images/django-crud-example-project-structure.png

My structure screenshot:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xRB0xcnkplZ4ktiyEblkMVeyJ1SpATDc

I think the error says the template does not exist but the templates exist.
Please inform me what is wrong in my application.

Comment: Could you include views.py, your entry in settings.py for TEMPLATES, and the directory within your project that your templates are in?  If Django can't find the template, it must be looking in a different place than you expect.

Comment: This error message is perfectly clear, your `/index` route (and therefore your `show` view) is asking for a template `show.html` that Django is unable to find. So, as @Atcrank says, we need to see both where you are keeping your templates, and how your template settings are set up.

Comment: I added my files. But the show.html exits.

Comment: thanks, but the linked screenshot doesn't show any html files, or any `templates` directories, so we don't know where the template is - which is obviously key. With your current template settings though, Django will only search in folders called `templates` which are inside one of your apps.  (`employee` appears to be your only app so far.) It's fine to use a top-level `templates` folder, but then you have to populate the `DIRS` array in the `TEMPLATES` setting with `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")`.

Comment: I added my file structure. Please let me know you opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py` file, the template directory needs to be assigned as:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Similarly, make sure that the templates have the following structure:

```
|-app_name
    |-templates
        |-app_name
            |-show.html
            |-index.html and so on
```

Comment: I added to my directory setting but still get an error which says page not found. Also, I added my file structure screenshot. Please let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I can't access your screenshot of your directories, I think its because of blocks on my end.  Sanip has (I think) the right answer. My meta-tip, having had a fair bit of difficulty learning how Django finds and uses templates, is to keep trying things; there's only so many wrong ways to do things.  For example, you could create a set of 'show.html' files that just contain a statement of the directory they are in, and put them in every directory within your project.
e.g. 
in project root folder:

```
#  show.html
<p> project root </p>
```

in your new 'templates' folder:

```
# employees/templates/show.html
<p> this one is in employees/templates/show.html
```

You shouldn't really need to do this, but if things are not working out, there's no harm. It takes 5 mins, you find out where Django is looking and reset.

Your template 'show.html' should be in a sub-directory called 'templates' of your app 'employees.'  My settings.py has 'DIRS': ['/templates/'], and 'APP_DIRS':True.  As a result, Django looks for a folder called 'templates' in all of my app directories. When I refer to a template in views.py, Django looks in all my apps (starting at the start of the list) for /templates/.  You can have subdirectories in a single templates directory if you like, and it can be a good way to ensure you don't accidentally call the wrong template for your next apps.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-DIRS